# How to validate the request body only contains certain fields?

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

How to use the express validator to ensure the body or query only contains certain fields? I.e something like:

```
 const { body, query } = require('express-validator/check')

 body.containsOnly("field1", "field2", "field3")

 query.containsOnly("queryParam1", "queryParam2")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let fields = ['field1', 'field2'];

function validateBody(body, fields) {
    for(key of fields) { 
        if(!body.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
            return false;
    }
    return true
}
```

You can use something like that